# How to call appdelegete method in different class in iphone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uiapplicationdelegate

I have a database with 10 tables. As I need to access this database in different view controllers, I have to declare the two methods shown below in each of them. Is there a way I can avoid this by declaring these methods in the application delegate. If yes, how can I go about using these methods in different classes.

```
- (NSString *) getWritableDBPath {

    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory , NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsDir = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
    return [documentsDir stringByAppendingPathComponent:DATABASE_NAME];
}

-(void)createEditableCopyOfDatabaseIfNeeded 
{
    // Testing for existence
    BOOL success;
    NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
    NSError *error;
    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory,
                                                         NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString *writableDBPath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:DATABASE_NAME];
    NSLog(@"%@",writableDBPath);

    success = [fileManager fileExistsAtPath:writableDBPath];
    if (success)
        return;

    // The writable database does not exist, so copy the default to
    // the appropriate location.
    NSString *defaultDBPath = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath]
                               stringByAppendingPathComponent:DATABASE_NAME];
    success = [fileManager copyItemAtPath:defaultDBPath
                                   toPath:writableDBPath
                                    error:&error];
    if(!success)
    {
        NSAssert1(0,@"Failed to create writable database file with Message : '%@'.",
                  [error localizedDescription]);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in your view controller first of all create a delegate variable

```
YourAppDelegate *appDelegate=(YourAppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication]delegate];
```

then u can call any methods that you have define in your delegate 
 like `[appDelegate methodName];`

Comment: then i want cretae like this [appdelegate getWritableDBPath];[appdelegate createEditableCopyOfDatabaseIfNeeded];

Comment: @rocky : in your .h file declare the delegate variable like  YourAppDelegate *appDelegate ; then in your .m file in viewLoad method write appDelegate=(YourAppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication]delegate]; now u can use appDelegate varible in whole .m file(in the same file)

Comment: @maulik i dont want to call this in viewLoad method i want call this varible in one method

Comment: @rocky : yes u can do it as well. I suggested you in general way. U can do so... and ya u have to import the delegate's .h file into the current view controller's .m file

Answer (score 1):

This just screams to be implemented as a separate controller with class level methods. I would highly recommend creating a Database controller with a definition like so:

```
@interface DatabaseController: NSObject  
    + (NSString *) getWritableDBPath ;
    + (void) createEditableCopyOfDatabaseIfNeeded  ;
@end
```

Then in your code using it as so:

```
#import "DatabaseController.h"


NSString * somePath = [DatabaseController getWritableDBPath];

[DatabaseController createEditableCopyOfDatabaseIfNeeded];
```

Comment: This is the stable and clean way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

Set them as public, so you can call them with [ ]

You just need to change the minus for +

```
+(void)createEditableCopyOfDatabaseIfNeeded;
```

Comment: what the mean can u tell me in detail

Answer (score 0):

first create a common instance for `appdelegate`.
otherwise in `constant.h` file create a instance like

```
 mAppDelegate=(YourAppDelegate*)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] ];
```

then just import **constant.h** and you may use `mAppdelegate` anywhere so using this you easily call

Answer (score 0):

You will need to define a protocol for this class and add a variable of that protocol to the member variable of this class as follows:

The classes where the object is created can either call this method using the object. The Best option is to use the app delegate class to implement these methods.

You can then assign the objects's delegate as the app delegate and call the methods.

```
@protocol mySqlDelegate ;

@interface mySqlClass  {

    id <mySqlDelegate> delegate;
}
@property (nonatomic, assign) id <mySqlDelegate> delegate;
@end



@protocol mySqlDelegate 

- (void) delegateMethodsForThisClass;

@end
```